# Sorting in AdvancedDatagrid in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I am using in-built sort functionality provided by AdvancedDatagrid.

I have multiple columns and suppose I have 10 rows. All 10 rows have the same data in one column.

If I sort on that column, then it sorts and the data in other columns which is different is also being sorted (reshuffled).

My requirement is if I am sorting on a column with same data, it should not sort the data in other columns.

To understand it better, check the link menioned below http://www.adobesystems.ca/devnet/flex/quickstarts/using_adg_control.html

In the above link mentioned, if you click on region column, other columns like territory or actual will change the values i.e. the rows gets reshuffled.

This should not happen as we are sorting on a column which has same values. Does anybody know how this can be handled in Flex 3 for AdvancedDataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that sorting function for all columns made not for fun in such way, and want to propose you to create separate column/grid with data you want sort separately, sou you'll able to sort it independently from other columns.

What will you say? :)